# Shifting bits instead of initial declaration

Tags: javascript, c#, bit-shift

I came accross unusual declaration in JavaScript (I've seen this in C# also):

```
var x = 1 << 0; // output: 1
```

Why and when should I use this ?

Edit: I've seen this in a context where there are declarations like this:

```
var orderByName = 1 << 0;
var orderByLastName = 1 << 1;
var orderByMiddleName = 1 << 2;
```

Comment: I don't see a reason. Maybe you could tell us since you're the one that's seen it in multiple places. Give us some context.

Comment: This is usually done to ensure a value is an integer (integer math is significantly quicker in some JS engines eg V8), but in this case that is already so, thus the shift is redundant.

Comment: It looks like that is done just for the sake of consistency - rather than necessity. So a matter of personal choice - in all probability it will be optimised out - so no extra code produced.

Answer (score 7):

When you have a set of numeric flags that are intended to be or'ed together, it's cleaner to declare them with shifts

```
var S_READ   = 1 << 0;
var S_WRITE  = 1 << 1;
var S_APPEND = 1 << 2;
var S_CREATE = 1 << 3;
```

instead of writing the powers of two explicitly (1, 2, 4, 8 etc)

My guess is that you saw this `1 << 0` in a similar context.

Comment: And of course that may now be considered a little redundant, since we have binary constants in C#7, e.g. `const uint S_WRITE = 0b0000_0010;`

Answer (score 1):

You should not. It's redundant. Just write `var x = 1;`.